# Firebase cloud messaging getting internal server error when calling "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wrote this code in spring boot(I am using Intellij IDE).In code androidFcmUrl= "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send". androidFcmKey=my server key. deviceToken=device id.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pushNotification", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void pushNotification() {
    try {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("Content-Type","application/json; UTF-8");
        httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "key=" + androidFcmKey);

        JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        msg.put("title", "Title");
        msg.put("body", "Message");
        msg.put("notificationType", "Test");

        json.put("data", msg);
        json.put("notification",msg);
        json.put("to", deviceToken);

        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(json.toString(), httpHeaders);
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(androidFcmUrl, httpEntity, String.class);
        System.out.println(response);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am getting Status 500 internal server error.

2018-11-28 17:42:47.712 ERROR 15292 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect] with root cause.

*But when I am hitting the api form postman with same payload I am getting a success response with message id.*

Comment: Your application cannot reach that URL. If it's available from the same machine with other software, disable your firewall or check why your application server cannot reach the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The `androidFcmUrl` you are trying to call is might not reachable. Ensure the path is correct and is listening. Also ensure if there is any proxy interrupting your URL.

Comment: But when I am hitting the api form postman with same payload I am getting a success response with message id. So I think the api call is reachable. Also if my firewall was blocking that url I would not have been able to hit it from postman. Am I wrong somewhere?. "also ensure if there is any proxy interrupting your URL".. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

some time IDE having diff conf setting then tool which you are using like postman. Its looks like issue of environment only. You can try to run app via OS console instead of IDE and you will see difference.